# How can I get referencing entity Id from referenced entity?

Tags: drupal-7, entityreference

I have 3 content types A, B, C. B and C have entity reference fields that reference to A and B and with different machine names. I want to get the parent node ID from referenced node.

A is referenced to B
B is referenced to C

Now if I am on A then I want to get B node id
and if I am on B then I want to get C node id.

How can I achieve this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) module, which can create a two-way reference when a single reference is set. That way it prevents having to search for the parent.

Otherwise, you can use Views, which can search for the parent via Relationships.